# Proving and deriving equation of a circle

Tags: circles

Attached below is the past examination question. I'll be presenting my thoughts and queries on it.

---

[image]

---

I initially thought of breaking this entire challenge down into multiple smaller ones.

- Prove any value of $\lambda$ represents a circle *through* $A(7,2)$ and $B(0,9)$
- Sketch the circle with through points $A$ and $B$, find the midpoint which should then be the center I suppose.
- Since the circle touches the y-axis, the radius would then be the length of the x-coordinate.

Below is a very rough sketch that came to mind:
[image]

How should I go about tackling this question? How would one prove the initial challenge?

Comment: You are aware that the circle in your sketch does *not* pass through $A$ and $B$? Also that it is unappropriately spcific in that its center is on $AB$?

Comment: I probably am not aware, otherwise I would have depicted it in the manner I thought correct. Which is why, my doubt brought me here to seek clarification on the challenge. Instead of putting a wall in front of my face, could you kindly steer me on the right path as the young student trying to learn that I am.

Comment: @Juxhin It *should be* obvious the circle you drew doesn't go through the points $\;A,B\;$ . This isn't putting a wall in front of your face, it is just checking you understand this, because if you do *not* understand this then I, and perhaps others, am not going to be able to help you...

Comment: Reason I drew it like that was because the question explicitly states that it *touches* the y-axis. I'm not sure how it could go through and simply touch (not cross) the y-axis.

Comment: If the equation touches the y equation. The discriminant of the quadratic equation when you put $x=0$ in the circle should be 0 :)

Comment: "Touches" doesn't usually mean "tangentially", as you drew it. If it intersects it then it *also* touches it...but *even* if it means tangentially you didn't draw it correctly.

Comment: @Timbuc "Touches" is meant ot be tangentially here. But that refers only to thew spcific case from the second part of the question. - The circle has to pass through $A,B$ nonetheless

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll try to redraw the circle and updated the diagram on the question to see if I understood correctly.

Comment: @Mann - Thanks again Mann, just noticed your comment. Could you explain how that helps in regards to this question?

Comment: @Juxhin , is the y axis tangent to the circle? As it says "touches" , it usually means tangent

Comment: @Juxhin Also remember that *if* the circle is tangent to the $\;y$ - axis, then the absolute value of the $\;x$-coordinate of the circle's **center** equals the circle's center...

Comment: @Mann I am not quite sure, that is the entire question and no other information is provided so I'm not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: Well one thing you can try is, that distance of centre of circle from y axis = radius from circle, this should give you equation for $\lambda$

Comment: Well, would the center be $(x-\frac{7}{2}) + (y-\frac{11}{2})$? If so then the absolute value of $x$ would be $x = \frac{7}{2}$?

Comment: No no , centre is not that your equation is $x^2+y^2+(\lambda-7)x+(\lambda-11)y+(18-9\lambda)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation represents a circle because it is quadratic in $x$ and $y$ with equal coefficients for $x^2$ and $y^2$ and no coccurance of $xy$, so that it can easily be transformed in to $$\tag1(x-u)^2+(y-v)^2=r^2$$ (with $u,v,r$ depending on $\lambda$). We don't need to explicitly perform the transformation, we just need to ensure that we won't end up with an imaginary or zero radius. But this is clear as we can verify by plugging in that $(7,2)$ and $(0,9)$ fulfill the equation.

If the circle touches the $y$-axis then clearly $(0,9)$ is the touching point. That implies that the center of the circle is at $y=9$. That is, the $v$ in $(19$ must equal $9$. That is, the llinear term in $y$ in the original equation must be $-18y$. We find that it is $(-11+\lambda)y$, so we need $\lambda=-7$. The equation becomes
$$x(x-7)+(y-9)(y-2)-7(x+y-9)=0 $$
or maybe more userfriendly
$$ x^2-14x+y^2-18y+81=0$$
or to allow reading off the center and radius:
$$ (x-7)^2+(y-9)^2=7^2.$$

To find the other tangent through the origin, we could reflect the point $(0,9)$ at the line through $(0,0)$ and the circle center $(7,9)$. But the reflection is easier with the point $(0,130)=9\cdot(7,9)+7\cdot(-9,7)$ because the reflection transforms it to $9\cdot(7,9)-7\cdot(-9,7)=(126,32)$. Hence the other tangent is the line through $(0,0)$ and $(126,32)$ (or as well through $(63,16)$).